# $scope binding vs $broadcast for an app timer

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am a little confused on what the best way to bind a Timer service's time value to a number of directives.  There are 2 methods done below and I am unsure of what is the best practice, or if there are performance advantages of one over the other.

In the code below there are 2 timers the first provides a return value, while the second broadcasts the time.  The controller updates its ticker value by calling the first factory's method, which the directives update their value via the $on call.

They both work just fine, but I am sure there are some advantages of one over the other.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('ticker');

/**
 * Timer that provides the current time when called directly
 */
app.factory('Timer', function($timeout) {

  var _currentTime = 0;

  var tick = function() {
    $timeout(function() {
      _currentTime += 1;
      tick();
    }, 2000);
  };

  tick();  // start the timer

  return {
    currentTime: function() { return _currentTime; }
  };

});


/**
 * Timer that broadcasts the current time
 */
app.factory('BroadcastTimer', function($timeout, $rootScope) {

  var _currentTime = 0;

  var tick = function() {
    $timeout(function() {
      _currentTime += 1;
      $rootScope.$broadcast('tick', _currentTime);
      tick();
    }, 2000);
  };

  tick();  // start the timer
});


/**
 * Handle the list of all the user's current stocks
 */
app.controller('StocksCtrl', function ($scope, Timer) {

  /**
   * List of all the user's current watched stocks
   */
  $scope.watchedStocks = [
    { name: 'Google', symbol: 'GOOG', closings: [ 20, 23, 25, 24, 26, 30, 26, 30, 34, 40, 47, 50 ] },
    { name: 'Apple',  symbol: 'AAPL', closings: [ 12, 15, 17, 13, 18, 21, 17, 24, 28, 33, 29, 34 ] },
  ];

  /**
   * Bind the current time to the Time factory
   */
  $scope.currentTime = function() {
    return Timer.currentTime();
  };

});


/**
 * Allows one to watch a stock and buy when the price is right.
 */
app.directive('watch', function(BroadcastTimer) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'watch.html',
    scope: {
      stock: '='
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
      /**
       * Listen to the BroadcastTimer's tick
       */
      $scope.$on('tick', function(event, time) {
        var timeIndex = time % $scope.stock.closings.length;
        $scope.price = $scope.stock.closings[timeIndex];
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one of the original author's of Angular,  Misko Hevery, take on events:

> "In general, for apps, events are less useful especially because Angular has data binding.  Many of the things that events are used for is data binding and we already did that for you.  So the question of whether or not to use events is how tightly coupled do you want two components to be.  If you really want them to be at a distance, then events may be the answer.  But most of the time injecting services or doing direct communication is probably preferred and a more robust way of dealing with these things.  But it depends on your case"

You can see his discussion of this in his talk, that I highly recommend  **"Angular Best Practices"**: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&list=TLJGdxZrHg3GcIgr_4ZzOcVQuXUhNWOOgt

Skip to 53:37 to hear him talk about this.

So, based on that alone I'd nudge you away from the $broadcast solution.  But I also bet that the $broadcast solution takes a bit more computation, especially on complex pages, as the DOM needs to be traversed.  But I have no data to back that up.

Comment: Thanks.  I watched that video before, but somehow I missed that part.